# Count distinct elements in every window using hash map

Tags: algorithm, algorithmic-trading, array-algorithms

Given an array A[] of size N and an integer K. Your task is to complete the function countDistinct() which prints the count of distinct numbers in all windows of size k in the array A[].

```
Constraints:
1 <= T <= 100
1 <= N <= K <= 105
1 <= A[i] <= 105 , for each valid i

Input:
The first line of input contains an integer T denoting the number of test cases. Then T test cases follow. Each test case contains two integers N and K. Then in the next line are N space separated values of the array A[].

Output:
For each test case in a new line print the space separated values denoting counts of distinct numbers in all windows of size k in the array A[].

Example(To be used only for expected output):
Input:
2
7 4
1 2 1 3 4 2 3
3 2
4 1 1

Output:
3 4 4 3
2 1
```

Solution:

```
void countDistinct(int A[], int k, int n) {
    map<int, int> hash;
    int cnt=0;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {
        if(i<k){
        hash[A[i]]++;
        }
        if(i==k-1) {
            cout<<hash.size()<<" ";
        }
        if(i>=k){
            if(hash[A[i-k]]==1){
            hash.erase(A[i-k]);
            } else {
                hash[A[i-k]]--;
            }
            hash[A[i]]++;
            cout<<hash.size()<<" ";
        }
    }    
}
```

where A[] is the array, n is the siz of array, k is the size of window.
Algorithm: 
1. Used a hash map to store count of elements until i==k.
2. When i==k, either decrement or erase A[i-k] count in the map; also increse count of A[i].
3. Print the hashmap size for the no of distinct counts in the window k.

Algorithm which i have used is O(n), but geeksforgeeks give Time Limit Exceeded error.
Am i going wrong anywhere ?

Comment: Maybe they want you to use array instead of map?

Comment: Thanks @DeepakTatyajiAhire

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably due to the use of map, as in map insertion and searching takes O(log N) time whereas in unordered_map, these operation take O(1) time in average. Also I think N and K are close to 10^5 in all the test cases, so by using map it takes O(T * N * O(log K)) making the time complexity in the range of O(100 * 100000 * 17) i.e O(1.7*10^8).

Therefore use **unordered_map** as follows:

```
void countDistinct(int A[], int k, int n) {
    unordered_map<int, int> hash;
    int cnt=0;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {
        if(i<k){
            hash[A[i]]++;
        }
        if(i==k-1) {
            cout<<hash.size()<<" ";
        }
        if(i>=k){
            if(hash[A[i-k]]==1){
                hash.erase(A[i-k]);
            } else {
                hash[A[i-k]]--;
            }
            hash[A[i]]++;
            cout<<hash.size()<<" ";
        }
    }
}
```

**Geeks For Geeks Verdict**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you're using an ordered hashmap which takes O(log N) for insertion, deletion, and searching elements in the map and so to reduce this to constant time you can use an unordered hashmap.

Refer this :

```
vector <int> countDistinct (int A[], int n, int k)
    {
        //code here.
        unordered_map<int,int>distinctN;
        vector<int>ans;
        //1 2 1 3 4 2 3
        //0 1 2 3 4 5 6
        
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
            if(i>=k){
                int firstIdx=i-k;  //
               
                if(distinctN[A[firstIdx]]>=1)
                {
                    distinctN[A[firstIdx]]--;
                    if(distinctN[A[firstIdx]]==0)
                    distinctN.erase(A[firstIdx]);
                }
            }
            
            distinctN[A[i]]++;
            if(i>=k-1){
                ans.push_back(distinctN.size());
            }
            
        }
        return ans;
    }
```